# select mysql missing columns in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i need to get the latest order (from our custon admin panel). here's my query:

```
select * 
from order 
  left join customer 
    on (customer.id = order.fk_cid) 
where date = curdate() 
order by time desc 
limit 1;
```

this output everything from orders and customers which i need except 1 therefore that is why i use the *

here's my table structure:

```
order table: 
id, fk_cid, date, time

customer table: 
id, name, lastname, street, city, zip, country, phone, email, lastlogin
```

now, in my php i have:

```
$result = mysql_query("
    select * 
    from `order` 
    left join customer 
    on (customer.id = order.fk_cid) 
    where date = curdate() 
    order by time desc 
    limit 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

at this point my order is not correct, why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `customers.id` is **overwriting** the `order.id` because you are using the same column name.

```
select * 
from `order` 
left join customer on (customer.id = order.fk_cid) 
where date = curdate() order by time desc limit 1;
+------+--------+------------+----------+------+-------+------
| id   | fk_cid | date       | time     | id   | name  | ....
+------+--------+------------+----------+------+-------+------
|    1 |      2 | 2011-11-30 | 07:01:23 |    2 | asasd | ....
+------+--------+------------+----------+------+-------+------
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

As you can see in this example you have two `id`, so PHP when retrieve the data using `mysql_fetch_assoc` it overwrites the second `id` because it's the **same key in the array**. To fix this, you will have to specify the columns in your query:

```
select `order`.id AS order_id, customer.id AS customer_id, customer.name /* etc... */
```

This will output:

Also, I recommend to use different name for your tables and fields. `order`, `date`, `time` since they are reserved word (in case you forget for use the **`** ).

```
Array
(
    [order_id] => 1
    [customer_id] => 2
    // etc...
)
```

Also here's a topic you should read: [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

Comment: all my queries use SELECT *, is that mean i have to change all of them?

Comment: if you want accurate data yes, specially if the name of all your columns are the same from tables to tables.

Comment: ouch, but yeah i see why i get some bugs now, thanks for your answer

Comment: The up side:  SELECT * is slower than SELECT `colName`